# Salvando dados em hexadecimal no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Preciso cadastrar no banco de dados um documento ou imagem no formato hexadecimal e depois recuperar esses dados convertendo-os da volta ao formato correto.

Comment: O que você quer exatamente, guardar ela em binário ou hexa? Ela está originariamente onde? Arquivo ou em string?

Comment: **Uma observação:** normalmente, nos casos práticos do dia-a-dia não tem muito sentido ficar trabalhando com os dados expandidos em formato hexadecimal, mas apenas gerá-los na hora da exibição ou uso final. Talvez você tenha um caso muito específico que realmente precise disso, mas é bom analisar bem. No caso de envio para impressoras, ou para trabalhar com endereços MAC, ou enviar _hashes_ e quaisquer tarefas similares, só faz sentido trabalhar com hexa na etapa final do processo (exibição, envio, etc). De qualquer forma, postei uma resposta neste sentido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O PHP já tem as funções próprias para isso:

```
string hex2bin ( string $data )
```

que converte a *string* hehadecimal passada no parâmetro `$data` num formato binário, que pode ser guardado num `BLOB` na base de dados, ou converter dados de um Varchar para *string*, se você estiver armazenando em hexa mas usando os dados em *bytes* ...

...e também a

```
string bin2hex ( string $str )
```

que converte a *string* passada em `$str` e retorna o hexadecimal correspondente, assim quando você recuperar os dados do `BLOB`, poderá convertê-los novamente para hexa, ou se estiver usando "ao contrário", pode pegar dados em bytes e utilizar esta função para converter os dados para uma *string* hexa, que pode ser guardada num Varchar.

Para usá-las, depende do seu caso prático. O importante é saber que ao pegar os dados em hexadecimal, pode passá-los para binário com `hex2bin`, efetivamente diminuindo seu espaço em 50%, para armazenar num `BLOB` na base de dados, e ao recuperar os dados do DB, basta usar a `bin2hex` para ter os dados em hexa novamente.

### Exemplos:

```
<?php
   $data = '546573746520646520636f6e76657273616f';
   echo hex2bin( $data );
?>
```

Saída:

```
Teste de conversao
```

```
<?php
   $data = file_get_contents( 'teste.jpg' );
   echo bin2hex( $data );
?>
```

Saída:

```
FFD8FFE102DE45786966000049492A00080000000F000001030001000000100A...
```

Comment: Será ou um documento doc, xml ou imagem (jpeg, jpg, png). Outra coisa, como estou trabalhando, aqui na empresa, com banco de dados MSSQL, SqlServer, não existe campo do tipo BLOB, então estou colocando o campo como nvarchar(50).

Comment: @GustavoSevero tanto faz o tipo de informação, o bin2hex resolve bem. De curiosidade, pq vc esta trabalhando com elas em hexa?

Comment: O motivo é que estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em PHP e já existe essa aplicação, porém, em aspx. E nessa aplicação aspx as imagens e documentos são cadastrados no banco dessa forma. Não programo em aspx.

Comment: @GustavoSevero provavelmente isso foi usado para guardar em strings comuns, para evitar o uso de BLOB. geralmente é um desperdício imenso de espaço. O bom seria você armazenar tudo em binário, e não usar mais o hexadecimal daí para frente. (mas é claro, é apenas uma suposição minha). Inclusive, de curiosidade, nas próprias ferramentas visuais que trabalham com mysql você pode ver os dados binários mostrados na tela representados como hexadecimal.

Comment: @GustavoSevero no SQlServer o equivalente do BLOB é o Varbinary. Varchar não serve pra dados binários. O bom é que com Varbinary  nao precisa do hexa tambem.

Comment: Certo. Mas e como se inseri no banco um dado, foto, por exemplo, em formato binário?

Comment: É só inserir sem converter pra hexadecimal (ou se estiver em hexadecimal já, basta converter conforme a resposta). Quando falo "binário", não é no sentido de notação numérica, mas sim do arquivo original. O arquivo é uma sequência de bytes, o Varbinary aceita qualquer sequência de bytes, sem ter que converter pra nada. Você pode ler o arquivo com `$dados file_get_contents()` e inserir no banco com `mysqli_send_long_data()`

Comment: Entendi. Achei que estavas falando em binário notação binária mesmo, mas entendi que não é. Obrigado.

Comment: @GustavoSevero é que eu fui "na onda" do termo usado na documentação do Varbinary e me expressei mal. PS: O exemplo no comentário foi de como gravar num banco MySQL.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17603/discussion-between-gustavosevero-and-bacco).

Comment: Bacco, consegui... Apenas assim: echo '<img src="'.$prefixo.'/'.$pasta.'/'.$nome.'" >';